# Big O notation and branching factor

Tags: performance

Lets say that you are trying to figure out what the best path to take is.  You have z number of possible moves and can make x number of moves at the same time.  You always do x number of moves at once, no more or less. How can you figure out the branching factor in terms of x and z?

Comment: What happens after the `x` moves? Do we still have the same `z` moves? New moves? `z-x` remaining moves? What about order? Can you give a real example of your question?

Comment: I've answered based on the information provided, but as Kobi pointed out your question is quite vague (as it stands, it has nothing to do with Big O).

Answer (score 1):

the branching factor in this example is 1 - the size of the problem is not increasing - you had `x` options to start with, you followed them all and you have the same number of available moves. You appear to be effectively taking 1 step down each of `x` straight lines at once. no branching is occurring unless i have misunderstood your question (whcih is possible, cause i don't see what `z` has to do with it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating `x` new states (one for each move valid move you can make) at every node then the branching factor is `x` if `x` is always less than `z`. If `z` is always less than `x` then the branching factor is `z` (as you can only make valid moves).